# Cannot upload attachment to SharePoint list item using JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, list-item, attachments

I am trying to upload the email attachment to SharePoint list item using JavaScript. But I landed up on the following error on the console.

> Cannot rename "_120" to "120": destination already exists.

Below is the code for the reference which I use for uploading attachment to SharePoint.

```
function processUpload(fileInput, listTitle, itemId,success,error) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (result) {
        var fileContent = new Uint8Array(result.target.result);
        performAttachmentUpload(listTitle, fileInput.name, itemId, fileContent,success,error);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput);
}


function performAttachmentUpload(listTitle, fileName, itemId, fileContent,success,error) {

    ensureAttachmentFolder(listTitle,itemId, 
       function(folder){
           var attachmentFolderUrl = folder.get_serverRelativeUrl();
           uploadFile(attachmentFolderUrl,fileName,fileContent,success,error);
       },
       error);
}


function ensureAttachmentFolder(listTitle,itemId, success,error)
{
      var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
      var web = ctx.get_web();
      var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
      ctx.load(list,'RootFolder');
      var item = list.getItemById(itemId);
      ctx.load(item);
      ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
            var attachmentsFolder;
            if(!item.get_fieldValues()['Attachments']) { /* Attachments folder exists? */
               var attachmentRootFolderUrl = String.format('{0}/Attachments',list.get_rootFolder().get_serverRelativeUrl()); 
               var attachmentsRootFolder = ctx.get_web().getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(attachmentRootFolderUrl);
               //Note: Here is a tricky part. 
               //Since SharePoint prevents the creation of folder with name that corresponds to item id, we are going to:   
               //1)create a folder with name in the following format '_<itemid>'
               //2)rename a folder from '_<itemid>'' into '<itemid>'
               //This allow to bypass the limitation of creating attachment folders
               attachmentsFolder = attachmentsRootFolder.get_folders().add('_' + itemId);
               attachmentsFolder.moveTo(attachmentRootFolderUrl + '/' + itemId);
               ctx.load(attachmentsFolder);
            }
            else {
               var attachmentFolderUrl = String.format('{0}/Attachments/{1}',list.get_rootFolder().get_serverRelativeUrl(),itemId); 
               attachmentsFolder = ctx.get_web().getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(attachmentFolderUrl);
               ctx.load(attachmentsFolder);
            }         
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                 function() {
                     success(attachmentsFolder); 
                 },
                 error);
        },
        error);
}


function uploadFile(folderUrl,fileName,fileContent,success,error)
{
     var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
     var folder = ctx.get_web().getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl);
     var encContent = new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray(); 
     for (var b = 0; b < fileContent.length; b++) {
         encContent.append(fileContent[b]);
     }
     var createInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();
     createInfo.set_content(encContent); 
     createInfo.set_url(fileName);
     folder.get_files().add(createInfo);
     ctx.executeQueryAsync(success,error);
}
```

I pasted the attachments link the File Explorer, I am able to open the "_120" folder but not able to view them or delete it.

What could be the solution for this.

**EDIT 1:-**

Well I think this can be the reason behind this error.
I just tried to open Attachment Folder of a list item on Windows Explorer and deleted the attachment from the folder of the list item ID i.e. 120.

After the deletion, when I tried to upload the attachment again to same list item it gave me the same error.

Is there any way that I can delete the attachment through SharePoint itself rather than opening the attachment folder in Windows Explorer.